# Self join query to SQlAlchemy ORM using alias

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to convert the following SQL query to a SQlAlchemy statement and facing the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join to
> <AliasedInsp at 0x7fa9c5832be0; Task(Task)>. Please use the
> .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as
> providing an explicit ON clause if not present already to help resolve
> the ambiguity.

SQL Query:

```
select t2.* 
from task as t1 
inner join task as t2 on t1.g_id  = t2.g_id  
where t1.id = 'task_id';
```

SQlAlchemy statement:

```
table_a = aliased(Task)
table_b = aliased(Task)
query = (
    self.db.query(Task)
    .join(table_a, table_b).filter(table_b.group_id == table_a.group_id)
    .filter(table_a.id == task_id)
   )
```

Tried following the SQLAlchemy documentation on alias but could not figure out the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
t1 = aliased(Task)
t2 = aliased(Task)

query = (
    self.db.query(t2)
    .select_from(t1)
    .join(t2, t2.g_id == t1.g_id)
    .filter(t1.id == task_id)
   )
```